# How to add rows to WPF grid in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is my `Mainwindow.cs` code

```
        Property p = new Property(RandomColumnName(),RandomColumnValues());
        records.Add(new Record(p ));
        ColumnCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();

        foreach (var column in columns) // creates grid with the specified columns
        {
            var binding = new Binding(string.Format("Properties[{0}].Value", column.Index));
            ColumnCollection.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = column.Name, Binding = binding });

        }
```

and in my XAML

```
       <StackPanel Margin="10,4,0,0">
            <DataGrid
             x:Name="dataGrid"
             cust:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding ColumnCollection}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=records}"/>
        </StackPanel>

public class Property:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public Property(string name,object value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}


  public class Record
{

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Property> _properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();

    public Record(params Property[] properties)
    {
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            _properties.Add(property);
        }
    }



    public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties
    {
        get { return _properties; }
    }


}
```

Now it add's only one row to the columns.

How can I add multiple rows ??

Thanks

Comment: What type is `records`?

Comment: @Sinatr - No, in this case it could be the implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged depending on the type of `records`

Answer (score 1):

why should it add more than one row, there's only one item added:

```
Property p = new Property(RandomColumnName(),RandomColumnValues());
records.Add(new Record(p ));
```

just add more `Record`s to the itemsource collection.